# Не заканчивается цикл в паскале

Tags: pascal

Не знаю почему но не заканчвается цикл, хотя код написан вро де бы правильно.

```
Program SUM1;
    var N, i, K1, K2: byte;
          S: integer;
    BEGIN
    write('vvedite K1 i K2 (K2>K1)');
    readln(K1, K2);
    S :=0;
    Repeat
    For i :=K1 to K2 do
    If i mod 3 = 0 then S := S + I;
    writeln('Summa=',S:5);
    until K1 > K2; 
    read;

end.
```

Comment: И какие данные вводите? Наверняка `K1 <= K2`...

Comment: @wololo да я ввожу  K1 <= K2 но цикл не заканчивается

Comment: В паскале цикл `repeat until` выполняется до тех пор, пока условие **ложно**

Comment: @wololo да я это знаю, так и должно  быть?

Comment: @wololo тоесть он и не должен заканчиватся

Comment: И в чём тогда проблема? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69000/discussion-between-brafik-and-wololo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просуммировать все, делящиеся нацело на 3, целые числа из отрезка `[K1, K2]`, `K1 <= K2` с применением цикла с постусловием можно так:

```
Program SUM1;
var N, i, K1, K2: Byte;
      S: Integer;
BEGIN
    Write('vvedite K1 i K2 (K2>K1)');
    ReadLn(K1, K2);
    S := 0;
    i := k1;
    repeat
        if i mod 3 = 0 then s := s + i;
        i := i + 1;
    until i > k2;
    WriteLn('Summa = ', s);
    Read; 
END.
```